# To reduce the size of image when uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i am uploading a document My aim is if it is a image document i have to reduce its size to 20 kb.Pls help me to do this.

```
string Uploadpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchFolder"];
                string strUploadpath = Uploadpath.TrimEnd("\\".ToCharArray()) + "\\" + strClientName + "\\" + strDocumentFolder + "\\";

                DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strUploadpath);
                if (!dInfo.Exists)
                {
                    dInfo.Create();
                }
 if (DocumentsUpload.FileName != null && DocumentsUpload.FileName != string.Empty)
                    {
                        DocumentsUpload.SaveAs((strUploadpath) + DocumentsUpload.FileName);
                       }
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885395/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-an-image-in-c-sharp-and-net-3-5

Answer (score 0):

An image size depends on few factors (size, resolution, format, compression, etc) and there is no guarantee that you could reduce it in exactly 20 kb without losing the quality. In order to change size of the file you can try to save new image adjusting its properties such as CompositingQuality, InterpolationMode, and quality and compression. For example, CompositingQuality could be set to "HighSpeed" value, InterpolationMode to "Low", etc. It all depends on what kind of images you have and it needs to be tested.

Example

```
//DocumentsUpload.SaveAs((strUploadpath) + DocumentsUpload.FileName);
Stream stream = DocumentsUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
Bitmap source = new Bitmap(stream);

Bitmap target = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target); 

EncoderParameters e;
g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed; <-- here
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low; <-- here 

Rectangle recCompression = new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height);
g.DrawImage(source, recCompression);

e = new EncoderParameters(2);
e.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 70); <-- here 70% quality
e.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW); <-- here

target.Save(newName, GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg"), e);

g.Dispose();
target.Dispose();

public static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string sMime)
{
   ImageCodecInfo[] objEncoders;
   objEncoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
   for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop <= (objEncoders.Length - 1); iLoop++)
   {
       if (objEncoders[iLoop].MimeType == sMime)
          return objEncoders[iLoop];
   }
   return null;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the target save it throws error in newName "Does not exist in current context"

Comment: Will it be applicable to all image format jpg,gif,png

Comment: newName is the name of the file to which to save this Image http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ytz20d80(v=vs.110).aspx It will work for all images but as you see it saves target in JPEG format

Answer (score 0):

this example works for .Net 4.5+ and upload several images at time. Also resizes the size of the image dynamically according to the value of the variable MaxWidthHeight. Excuse my bad english.

Example

```
private void  UploadResizeImage()
    {
        string codigo = "";
        string dano = "";
        string nav = "";
        string nombreArchivo = "";
        string extension = "";
        int cont = 0;
        int MaxWidthHeight = 1024; // This is the maximum size that the width or height file should have
        int factorConversion = 0;
        int newWidth = 0;
        int newHeight = 0;
        int porcExcesoImg = 0;
        Bitmap newImage = null;
        string directory = "dano";
        System.Drawing.Image image = null;
        string targetPath = "";

        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["codigo"]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["dano"]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["nav"]))
            {
                codigo = Request.QueryString["codigo"].ToString();
                dano = Request.QueryString["dano"].ToString();
                nav = Request.QueryString["nav"].ToString();

                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(directory));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(directory + "/" + nav));

                string fechaHora = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
                nombreArchivo = codigo + "-" + dano + "-" + fechaHora;


                string html = "<h4>Se cargaron con éxito estos archivos al servidor:</h4>";
                if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
                {
                    html += "<ul>";
                    foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
                    {
                        cont++;
                        extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(UploadImages.FileName);
                        targetPath = Server.MapPath("~/" + directory + "/" + nav + "/").ToString() + nombreArchivo + "-" + cont.ToString() + extension;
                        if (extension.ToLower() == ".png" || extension.ToLower() == ".jpg")
                        {
                            Stream strm = null;
                            strm = uploadedFile.InputStream;
                            //strm = UploadImages.PostedFile.InputStream;
                            using (image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm))
                            {
                                string size = image.Size.ToString();
                                int width = image.Width;
                                int height = image.Height;

                                if (width > MaxWidthHeight || height > MaxWidthHeight)
                                {
                                    porcExcesoImg = (width * 100) / MaxWidthHeight; // excessive size in percentage
                                    factorConversion = porcExcesoImg / 100;
                                    newWidth = width / factorConversion;
                                    newHeight = height / factorConversion;
                                    newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                                    var graphImage = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
                                    graphImage.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                                    graphImage.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                                    graphImage.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                                    var imgRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                                    graphImage.DrawImage(image, imgRectangle);
                                    newImage.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    uploadedFile.SaveAs(targetPath);
                                }



                                html += "<li>" + String.Format("{0}", uploadedFile.FileName) + "</li>";
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    html += "</ul>";
                    listofuploadedfiles.Text = html;
                }
                else
                {
                    listofuploadedfiles.Text = "No se ha selecionado ninguna imagen!";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                listofuploadedfiles.Text = "No se recibieron los parámetros para poder cargar las imágenes!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            listofuploadedfiles.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```