# image compression c# and recoverred in android

Tags: c#, android, image, compression

I am storing an image in sql server from a c# application and displaying it in android.

I am getting a memory problem in android and the queries to sql are taking to much time so, I would like to know a way to compress the image in c# to, for example, 100 KB, and store it in sql with this size.

--EDIT

This is the code when displaying the image in android:

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myLote.getFoto(), 0, myLote.getFoto().length);      
    imageFoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

imageFoto is the ImageView and "myLote.getFoto()" returns the byte[]

```
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:428)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:446)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at com.example.subasta.FragmentSubasta.onViewCreated(FragmentSubasta.java:109)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-06 18:03:41.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6462):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

--REEDIT

I am not getting now any error but nothing is displayed :( :

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    Bitmap preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myLote.getFoto(), 0, myLote.getFoto().length, options);
    imageFoto.setImageBitmap(preview_bitmap);
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Do you need to store the image, or can you store a URI to its location instead?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but it is not possible to get an image from my pc, load it into an URL and display it in the android device right?

Comment: your saving the image in a folder and save in the SQL the url to the image Location .. in the client you only take the url location and read the image.

Comment: in android, to get the image by using URL, the image needs to be downloaded so it will required the same time

Comment: what Error are your gettings with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the lower common that possible save the image in SQL as byte array  `byte[]`
then you can convert from `byte[]` to `Bitmap` in Android.

Comment: I am doing that, but I need to compress it before storing into sql

Comment: well you have 2 choices : reduce the image size or the change the format of the image to .PNG for example which one do you want?

Comment: Reducing the size should be the solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885395/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-an-image-in-c-sharp-and-net-3-5 hope it helps. its C# lang

Comment: it is storing good now, but I keep getting the error when trying to display it in android. This is the code:

Comment: sorry cant see any code please publish in your question