# How to change the image size?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

How to change the size of the image stored on the disk?

```
function doGet() {
  var file =  DriveApp.getFileById("-ID-");
  if (file.getMimeType() == "image/jpeg") {
    //?
  }
}
```

Comment: Refer to this maybe?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885395/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-an-image-in-c-sharp-and-net-3-5

Comment: google-apps-script ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly possible in Google Apps Script. The only way would probably be to call an (external) API using [urlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/).

I looked around and it seems that there are some API available on line (for example [imageshack](http://imageshack.com/pages/resize/)) but I didn't go further in my tests...