# How convert Bitmap from 24bbp to 1bpp in .net compact framework?

Tags: .net, compact-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert image to 1 bpp bitmap in .net compact framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836632/convert-image-to-1-bpp-bitmap-in-net-compact-framework)

I found this related answer on stackoverflow: [Convert image to 1 bpp bitmap in .net compact framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836632/convert-image-to-1-bpp-bitmap-in-net-compact-framework)

I found just the Namespace Microsoft.Win32 in compact framework.
Visual Studio say e.g.

> Win32.CreateDIBSection and Win32.CreateCompatibleDC and
>   Win32.SelectObject and Win32.DeleteDC is not a Member from this
>   Namespace.

Can you help me please?

Comment: You need to import coredll.dll.  The thread you linked to explains this.

Comment: Hello Ramhound, hello Chris, thanks for your comments. I have now coredll imported and convertion works fine. i have now the problem, that when i store the bitmap as file then is the bit-deep 24Bit again and not 1Bit :-/ I need 1Bit bitmapfile for send to a bluetoothprinter. Any ideas or codesnipets for me please? Sorry for my english i am from germany.