# .Net Compact Framework Printing in c#

Tags: compact-framework

i want to print out of my c# application on my hendheld , but i cant find the Printdocument object. After a bit of searching i find out that the printdfocument doesnt exist in the compact framework. But is there another my to print with my WLan PCL5 printer?

All these third party lib like PrintCe are very expensive and i think i dont really need them because, i want to use the PCL5 Interface of my printer. I cant imagine that the only way to print something in compact framework should be third party softwráre, which is ten years old and very expensive. I mean printing is a very common thread.

Can anybody me out?

thanks!

Comment: Are you in control of your OS image? If you are, platform builder has an example PCL driver which you can add to your windows image. I believe you'd have to go from there... it would probably be much easier (and cheaper really) to buy the 3rd party library

Comment: You should realize printing capabilities on server

Answer (score 2):

The Compact Framework has no printing capabilities. You can roll your own - I did this way back in the CF 1.0 days, creating a 1bpp image, drawing everything to it, then shipping that to the printer, but it was a lot of work ([some of it can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836632/convert-image-to-1-bpp-bitmap-in-net-compact-framework)) and really it only supported the specific report I was making for the specific Zebra printer I was targeting.

Becasue of the complexity involved, just about everyone that I have ever known to do printing in the CF has used [PrinterCE](http://www.fieldsoftware.com/PrinterCE.htm) or [PrintBoy](http://www.bachmannsoftware.com/pbce.htm).